# How to convert string with backslash to char

Tags: string, ocaml

I have to convert a backslash `string` into `char`, but it seems that casting doesn't exist like in java:
`String msg = (Char) new_msg`

I have to convert `string` values like `"\t"`, `"\n"`, `"\000"`-`"\255"` to `char`.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used Java, but I seriously doubt that you can just "cast" a `String` to a `Char`.

Comment: @glennsl java has "char" or "Character" types, and the casting doesn't work like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first start questioning why you have a single character string in the first place, and whether you can be sure that that is what you actually have. But given that it is, you can get a `char` from a `string`, whether it's in the first position or any other, using either [`String.get`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/String.html#VALget), or the more convenient string indexing operator:

```
let s = "\t"

let c: char = String.get s 0

let c: char = s.[0]
```

But note that these will both raise an `Invalid_argument` exception if there is no character at that position, such as if the string is empty, for example.

Comment: When I use String.get s 0 I either get ' \ ' or ' t ' but I don't get the char ' \t '

Comment: Then it seems you actually have a string with two or more characters, rather than one with a single character like `'\t'`. That is indeed a very different problem, that might require proper parsing, but it's not entirely clear what the actual requirements are. Hence why you've gotten answers that are very different from what you expected. There isn't a universal standard for escape codes, so first you'd have to lay out what the escape codes are, and what they mean. Or you could refer to an existing specification [like OCaml's](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/lex.html#sss:character-literals).

Comment: You should also explain what you expect to happen if the input string is not a valid escape code.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to glennsl's answer, both methods will raise an `Invalid_argument` exception if the string is empty. If you were writing a function to get the first char of a string, you might use the `option` type to account for this.

```
let first_char_of_string s =
  try Some s.[0]
  with Invalid_argument _ -> None
```